# Google Analytics track which pages have embedded widget

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to use Google Analytics on a javascript widget that my clients will embed on their site. The widget is loaded via AJAX and lives on the page itself, not in an iframe, so it is therefore part of the page. Every time a user hits the page, I want to log that hit along with the URL of the page and record it in my dashboard.

I added a custom dimension called `widgetviews` to my script and created a custom report that tracks `widgetviews`, however I'm not sure if I set up the code and/or report correctly, as I am not seeing any results being logged. I also tried setting up a custom variable called `widgetviews` before I read that custom variables don't work with the older `analytics.js` library, which is what I'm using.

Here is my code snippet:

```
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-46642836-1', 'mysite.com');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('set', 'dimension1', window.location.href);
```

I think I have my code set up correctly, however it doesn't seem to be logging any activity. I'm still pretty new to GA. The most I've done with it is insert the script and log standard metrics.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing your Universal syntax with Classic syntax. The analytics.js library does not recognise custom variables anymore, so you will need to use custom dimensions instead, and remove the line

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'widgetview', 'window.location.href', 3]);
```

You should also set the dimension before the pageview hit.

Remember to define your custom dimension in the GA config as well, with the correct slot and scope.

Comment: I thought slots were only for custom variables. Or are you referring to the index? The index for widgetviews is 1.

Comment: Custom dimensions occupy certain slots (of which you only 20 if you are not on Premium). You have to define your CD, along with the scope, in the GA config before you use them.

Comment: So I have my CD defined and my script above (updated with current code). Am I missing anything else? Do I need to add my `dimension1` variable to the `send` function or does the `set` function do that for me? E.g.: `ga('send', 'pageview', {'dimension1': window.location.href});`

Comment: You should set the CD before the pageview is sent, or send it along with the pageview as you have indicated.